# What's the best way to sculpt or texture without a drawing pad?

Tags: mesh, texturing, workflow, sculpting

I need to make custom sculpted or textured things, and I notice the restrictions of using just a mouse versus having a drawing pad or display tablet.

The workflow is very jotted, unnatural feeling, and just slower when sculpting or texturing with just a mouse.

For those who don't have a drawing pad, but are doing modeling tasks that would encourage one, what are some tips to make the work more efficient?

Comment: The best way is to leverage it as a feature and make it the art style. Own it and admit the bad quality intencionality if you don't want to spend ages on it. Searching for a best way with a mouse yields different methods for different people and it's irrelevant in the end, it's always orders of magnitude more tedious.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get yourself a tablet if you feel you need one. There is nothing wrong with sculpting with a mouse only as well, it will be a different experience and it will tend to take longer because you cannot control the pressure, but you can draw a couple of weaker strokes on top of each other so it's kind of similar to one stoke that is stronger in some parts. If you practice more you will get more efficient at it. It is generally easier and faster to sculpt and draw with a tablet. If you just got one and it feels terribly uncomfortable to use it, don't worry, that is natural, you need time to get used to a tablet once you start using it. The unnatural feeling should go away in a few months of using it.